# How to deinit UnityFramework in Swift application

Tags: ios, swift, unity-game-engine, memory-management

I have a Unity project embed into a native Swift project. Unity part is used for a short period of time (as a mini-game). It should be presented and then to be dismissed. I have no issues with displaying it, but there is no proper way to dismiss `UnityAppController`. The only workaround how to dismiss it is next:

```
// unityFramework object is `UnityFramework`
// unloadApplication is called before
func unityDidUnload(_ notification: Notification!)
{
    print("unityDidUnload")
        
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        
    self.unityFramework?.unregisterFrameworkListener(self)
    self.unityFramework?.appController()?.window.resignKey()
    self.unityFramework?.appController()?.window = nil
        
    self.unityFramework = nil
}
```

The code above removes the game from the main windows, but it still stays in memory.

Functions available within `UnityFramework` doesn't help at all. `- (void)unloadApplication;` just freezes the Unity app; `- (void)quitApplication:(int)exitCode;` kills the main app.